# How to import a custom keyboard layout from macOS ukelele into ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am a total beginner with ubuntu.  I costumized a keyboard layout with the software ukelele in macOS Sierra. I am trying out ubuntu in a virtualbox and would like to import my costum keyboard layout into ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You can edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/xx`. Copy the original file to keep the backup.

Comment: When I needed to change my keyboard, I modified: sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/cz
Then I controlled that with setxkbmap -option grp:win_space_toggle -layout 'cz,cz_jk' -variant 'rus_quertz'. But I do not know how to import from macOS.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer and the welcome. Unfortunately, that will cost a lot of time. If there is no other option, I'll consider it.